# PyQt, PyDev and Windows Firewall

Tags: pyqt, pydev, firewall

I have problems with autocompletion in Eclipse IDE and PyDev plugin. Especially with PyQt imports. It simply hangs and occasionaly reports: `Error connecting to python process (Name:Python 3.2:EndName:`
After searching for a while I think the problem is the Windows Firewall, which blocks the communication of PyDev and Python.
Can someone tell me what EXACTLY do I need to setup in the Windows (and/or Domain?) firewall to make PyDev autocompletion work? What program(s) should I enable?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an exception to your firewall so that Eclipse (actually, the java process) can read/write to the localhost 127.0.0.1 (note that to make sure this is your problem, you can temporarily disable the firewall just to check if that's really it -- and if it is, reenable it and create the exception).